# Automator action keeps failing

Tags: applescript, automator

I would like to have a very simple Automator action that watches my photo upload folder in Dropbox and moves every file that it receives into another folder on my desktop. Sometimes it works perfectly, other times it refuses to work even after a reboot. I have attached  the folder action I am using.

This is Automator at its simplest and I'm not sure why it won't work!

[image: Automator]

Comment: Are they large files? Could it be the files are locked by Dropbox while being transferred and the Folder Action is kicking in too early??

Comment: Are you seeing [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/64258/55365) in your log? I am on a simple test I did...

Comment: Vic, apologies for late reply, I'll check this out when I'm home.

Comment: The log in Automator says that: 

"2015-06-03 10:49:15 +0000: The action “Move Finder Items” was not supplied with the required data."

That is all. Regarding the link  I suppose some of the photos may be being uploaded quicker than every ten seconds.